# Эмуляция usb устройства на компьютере для внешнего компьютера (подключеного по usb)

Tags: usb, libusb

Нужно что бы компьютер распознавался как мышка (либо другое устройство) для подключеного по usb пк или смартфона. То есть на комьютере есть специальный свой драйвер который эмулирует мышку. Или сделать проще перенаправить входные данные с "usb порт 1" (к которому подключена мышка) на выход "usb порт 2" (к которому подключен смартфон). Таким образом при подключении смартфона к пк, он распознает пк как мышь.

Я только начал осваивать разработку под usb (libusb) и не могу понять как такое реализовать. Возможно ли такое вообще реализовать? Можете подсказать какие шаги нужно выполнить и в какую область залезать.